# How can I add horizontal lines to a BarPlot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, charts, core-plot

I want to know how could I add Horizontal lines to each bar of a barPlot with different values. 
I want to let the customer know what is the expected value with an horizontal line and what is his real value with a bar.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second bar plot. Set `barBasesVary` = YES on the second plot. It will ask the datasource for an additional field called `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase`. Return a base value and tip value that will make a short bar.